# Angularjs: ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Consider this example. I have a list of galleries that each have a unique client selected. I can also change the client of a particular gallery. To do this I have created a client list in a select/option list.

```html
<select ng-model="clientList" ng-options="client.id as client.clientName for client in clients" >
     <option value="">Choose Client</option>
</select>
```

The list is populated from DB. Usually I use the client.id to make item selected. Being new to Angularjs, it seems that it assigns it's own values to the value="". In my example, the gallery table has a client column listing that unique clientID relating to the client table and the client.id. How do I make the correct client selected?

**Controller**

```js
function imageGalleryCtrl ($scope, images, clients, galleries)
{

    $scope.panes = [
        { title:"Home", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/create.html", active: true },
        { title:"Upload", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/upload.html"},
        { title:"Edit", content:"/beta/application/views/images/uploader/edit.html"}
    ];

    //close modal
    $scope.close = function () {
        $scope.imageUploader = false;
    };

    //get gallery info on click from table
    $scope.getGallery = function(id, gallery)
    {
        //set gallery ID to scope
        $scope.galleryID = id;

        //open the modal
        $scope.imageUploader = true;

        //get gallery information
        $scope.galleryCollection = galleries.getGallery(id);

        $scope.galleryCollection.then(function(galleries){
            $scope.gallery = galleries.thisGal;
        });

        //get clients
        $scope.clientCollection = clients.getClients();

        $scope.clientCollection.then(function(clients){
            $scope.clients = clients.clients;
            //Set client
        });

        //get all the images 
        $scope.imgCollection = images.getImages(id);

        $scope.imgCollection.then(function(images){
            $scope.images = images.thisGal_images;
        });
    };
}
```

**Service**

```js
myApp.factory('galleries', function ($http, $q)
{
    return {
        getGallery: function (id)
        {
            var deferred = $q.defer(id);

            $http.post('/beta/images/get/', {id: id}).success(function(data)
            {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});
```

The client service is pretty much the same, just referencing the proper url

Thanks for the help

[image: console.log]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is model driven, you need to set $scope.clientList to the client id. In your controller you can do something like this

```js
function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.clients = [{
        id: 1,
        clientName: 'Joe'
    }, {
        id: 2,
        clientName: 'Tom'
    }, {
        id: 3,
        clientName: 'Bob'
    }];

    $scope.clientList = 2; //clientList is the model defined in the select directive
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aKD9P/)**</kbd>

And if the `id` field is a string, you should set `clientList` as string rather than integer:

```
$scope.clientList = "245";
```

Comment: thanks, looks like my issue lies elsewhere. Your fiddle works perfectly. Setting the $scope.clientList doesn't have any effect on the select list. I'll update my question with the whole controller to see if that uncovers anything

Comment: entire controller up.

Comment: seems working actually. http://jsfiddle.net/aKD9P/2/ What error did you see in your code?

Comment: I think the problem is the (clients), i added screenshot of output console.log(clients);

Comment: Looks like the id field is string type not an integer, try $scope.clientList = "245";

Comment: Yes! -- thanks so much for the help on this and my other questions. Trying to get my head angularized.